# Gmail wrongly shows "Virus Detected" message on APK attachment

Tags: android, gmail, apk, email-attachments

I have been getting "Virus Detected" message on Gmail for one the `Android` apps I have been developing. Weirdly enough, its not that Gmail does not allow apk attachments, because I have emailed various other apk's before on Gmail, and those apps can still be attached and sent successfully. Only this app is having such problems.

So my question is, what could possibly be the problem here and where should i look to fix it in the application?

[image]

Comment: is it in mobile, website or both?

Comment: try in mobile by installing it I think you can tell google that it is not virus

Comment: yes, I have installed the app in mobile. Still same.

Comment: @Munir Basheer, have you found the exact solution.Please reply.

Comment: @jagdish No i didn't find a solution with regards to gmail. We are now using file sharing services to send out .apk files in our organization. Email + download link, works great

Comment: try these fixes-
1. change the name of the apk from app-release to anything else.
2. remove the cc in the mails and send to single person.
3. put to driver or wetransfer and send the link.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail poorly support apk attachments. Use other methods such as,

Dropbox.

Comment: Zipping the apk and google drive does not work either. I have had to use dropbox the last time.

Comment: Yes. I also uses dropbox. Try mediafire also. I didn't tried

Comment: I have attached many times in gmail, but today i got error. why???